# How do I build a user table with aggregated article data?

Tags: 7, css-js-aggregation

I'm new to Drupal, and I want to make an overview over aggregated user data related to the articles they have written.

I basically want to build a table like this:

```
------------------------------------------------------
| user | articles published | articles with comments |
------------------------------------------------------
| bob  |                 12 |                      3 |
------------------------------------------------------
| sue  |                 34 |                      0 |
------------------------------------------------------
| kim  |                  0 |                      0 |
------------------------------------------------------
```

What is the best way to make a table like this? Is this something I need to make my own module for?

Would it be possible to aggregate this with an existing module?

Comment: Which version of Drupal you are using ?

Comment: I'm using Drupal 7.15.

Comment: Ok, You can use below code then in a custom block with format as PHP. I hope you are using default Article Content Type that comes with Drupal Installation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to the Drupal StackExchange !

You can achieve this with some custom php code and couple of queries.

```
<?php

   $articles_publishers = db_query("SELECT DISTINCT u.uid FROM {node} n LEFT JOIN {users} u on n.uid = u.uid where n.type = 'article'");
   foreach ($articles_publishers as $articles_publisher) {
     $publisher = user_load($articles_publisher->uid);
     $username = theme('username', array('account' => $publisher));
     $articles_published = db_query("SELECT count(*) FROM {node} where uid = :uid and status = 1 and type='article'", array(':uid' => $articles_publisher->uid))->fetchField();
     $articles_published_with_comments = db_query("SELECT count(*) FROM {node} n INNER JOIN {comment} c ON n.nid = c.nid where n.uid = :uid and n.status = 1 and n.type='article'", array(':uid' => $articles_publisher->uid))->fetchField();

     // Theme the information with above results

     print "Username :" . $username;
     print "articles published :" . $articles_published;
     print "articles with comments :" .  $articles_published_with_comments;
   }

?>
```

use above code in a module custom block or Add Block with php option to display the information.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you! When I go through the Add block form, I never see any "php option". Is this due to my Drupal verson (7.15), or am I just missing it?

Comment: Enable PHP filter module to see the PHP format !

Comment: Aha! Tanks Anil! Sorry about not voting you up, I don't have enough reputation yet :-)